# How to redirect (htaccess) any one file on any subdomain to a new single subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess

So I have a file

**www.example.com/for/ldt.php?do=test**

But this file can be found on www1.example.com, www2.example.com and so on

I want to redirect all users no matter what www subdomain the person is coming from to a single subdomain of **cdn.example.com**

The kicker here is I dont want to redirect for all files or requests, only if they are trying to access **ldt.php** which is a dynamic script so it can have a bunch of arguments too

Finally, when the change is made with htaccess, is it possible for the url to physically change in the address bar too?

Can all this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a rewriteRule that redirects the file based on `HTTP_HOST` headers or only if the requested host is not `cdn.example.com` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cdn\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^for/ldt\.php$ http://cdn.example.com/for/ldt.php [L,R]
```

This will automatically append the querystring `?do=test` to the end of the destination URL.

Comment: Thank you, its strange, this totally works when I place these as the only lines in my htaccess file, but when I put it after another line forcing https  ( RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] )   then this doesnt work at all.   Im coming in from a https request, so I dont think its triggering the first https match and should goto the second one which is yours.  Is there any reason you can think of?

Comment: Actually this works in an online tester, but even if i remove all rules and place only this one on the live server it doesnt want to work... ?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, I was running it from the for folder, so i just had to remove that from the redirect rule :)